# System.setClipboard not working for ios (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, text, clipboard

This question has been asked before but it was a few years ago and there was no clear cut answer

Simply put

```
System.setClipboard(this.text);
```

Is not working for ios publishings, although the code is working with no problems in a mac osx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this

```
import flash.desktop.Clipboard;
import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;

Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT,this.text);
```